# список указателей на объекты и удаление из списка

Tags: c++, указатели, list

Как получить доступ к ним по итератору, чтобы можно было удалять объект из коллекции?

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void doit() { cout << "Base!\n"; }
    virtual ~Base() { cout << "deleted...\n"; }
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    void doit() override { cout << "Derived!\n"; }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    list <unique_ptr<Base>> v;
    v.emplace_back(new Base);
    v.emplace_back(new Derived);
    v.emplace_back(new Base);
    v.emplace_back(new Derived);
    v.emplace_back(new Base);

    for(auto& o: v) o->doit();
}
```

Как получить доступ к объектам по итератору, чтобы можно было удалять объект из коллекции?

Как заменить строчку

```
 for(auto& o: v) o->doit();
```

на цикл

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->doit();
    }
```

Или как мне удалить в цикле for(auto& o: v) элемент из коллекции v?

Comment: `(*it)->doit()` , только тогда вместо unique_ptr нужен shared_ptr видимо

Comment: удалять внутри цикла с использованием итератора не рекомендуется. Обычно сначала находите итератор на требуемый элемент ( вручную в цикле или одним из семейства функций std::find*), а потом у контейнера вызывается метод удаления элемента, принимающий итератор (уже вне цикла). подробнее в документации по std::list

Comment: Большое спасибо vegorov, почему-то не смог отметить Ваш комментарий, как ответ. Действительно, надо же разименовать указатель! Элементарно! Когда известен ответ, кажется так просто. По поводу циклов удаления вне цикла буду иметь ввиду, хотя в моём случае должно нормально работать (списко не пустой и эти объекты не смогут оказаться в конце). Большое спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: shared_ptr не нужен, потому-что *it вернёт ссылку